# How do I mockImplementation of Jest function mock used for react-i18next useTranslation hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-i18next

I have a fairly simple Component, it uses the `react-i18next` `useTranslation` hook.

I had been using the following in a component test. It did as expected by returning the first param `key` as it's return value.

```js
jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: key => key }),
}));
```

Next I wanted to use a translation that used the built in variable substitution, at this point the above function for `t` couldn't provide enough data as the second parameter is ignored. So I switched it for a mock function.

```js
const mockTranslation = jest.fn().mockImplementation(key => key);

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  useTranslation: () => ({ t: mockTranslation }),
}));
```

I can confirm that within the component `t` is definitely a mock function. I can confirm within the test that `mockTranslation.mock.calls` is picking up all the correct call parameters. It is **not** using the defined implementation to return first param as it's value. `mockTranslation.mock.results` shows a series of return types that have a value of `undefined`. I even attempted a basic `jest.fn().mockReturnValue('TEST')` and still the results show an `undefined` value.

I'm not sure what I have done incorrectly here. Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Have you tried from this page?
https://react.i18next.com/misc/testing

Comment: @gypsyCoder Absolutely, that's where I started out. Nothing in there describes the use of a mock function in place of `t`, only a standard function. I dropped the `i18n` key as it doesn't make a difference either way for my requirements